# Push using passphrased SSH key

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

I have a Pod on OpenShift 3.11 (Kubernetes 1.11). From that POD I need to push to a GitHub Repository using a passphrased SSH-Key.
Now I can create a secret just fine:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  known_hosts: Yml...
  passphrase: abcde...
  ssh-privatekey: LS0...
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-ssh-mirror
  namespace: mynamespace
type: kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
```

I have not idea though, how then to hook up this Secret in a way, that the Pod would work with both the Privatekey as well as the Passphrase.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `passphrase` and `ssh-privatekey` fields in the `data` section of the `git-ssh-mirror` secret created can be mounted inside the container either as:

- [Environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables), or
- [Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)

  1. Mounting secret as **environment variables** `GIT_SSH_PASSPHRASE` and `GIT_SSH_PRIVATEKEY` inside the container:

  ```
  ...
  kind: Pod
  ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      image: myimage
      env:
        - name: GIT_SSH_PASSPHRASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: git-ssh-mirror
              key: passphrase
        - name: GIT_SSH_PRIVATEKEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: git-ssh-mirror
              key: ssh-privatekey
  ```

  Now, use the environment variables `GIT_SSH_PASSPHRASE` and `GIT_SSH_PRIVATEKEY` inside the container to access the SSH passphrase and private key respectively needed to push to the GitHub repository.

  2. Mounting secret as **files** inside the container:

  ```
  ...
  kind: Pod
  ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      image: myimage
      volumeMounts:
      - name: git-ssh-secrets
        mountPath: "/etc/mypath"
        readOnly: true
    volumes:
    - name: git-ssh-secrets
      secret:
        secretName: git-ssh-mirror
  ```

  Now, the values of `passphrase` and `ssh-privatekey` in the `git-ssh-mirror` secret created are `base-64` decoded and stored in the read-only files `/etc/mypath/passphrase` and `/etc/mypath/ssh-privatekey` respectively inside the container. Use them to push to the GitHub repository.

If the passphrase or SSH private key needs to be `base-64` decoded, use the `base64 --decode` command.

Comment: Cannot find any reference to `GIT_SSH_PASSPHRASE` and/or `GIT_SSH_PRIVATEKEY`. Also they do not work for me. Do you have any reference for there?

Comment: Refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod to use secrets in pods.